# How to store non persistent java object in redis cache java

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, redis-cache

I have `EmployeeDto` as an `Object`, which is not synced with the database.

I want to put `EmployeeDto` inside Redis cache. I have gone through an example where I can see database entity is getting cached using Redis cache but how can we store and retrieve non-database entity in Redis cache?

```
@Getter
@Setter 
public class EmployeeDto {
    private long employeeId;
    private String requestId;
    private String timestamp;
    private String employeeName;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share EmployeeDto class?

Comment: @GuyKorland I have added EmployeeDto.

Comment: So you're using Spring-Data-Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland Yes we are using Spring-Data-Redis.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a concept of CacheManager in Spring cache lib.

CacheManager allows you to create Cache with any name, for your use case you can create a cache with the name `default` and this cache must be of Redis as you need it.

You can inject `CacheManager` in any bean, once you have `cacheManager` object you can call `getCache` method to get the `Cache` object now you need to call the appropriate method on this cache object to store/retrieve data.

See many usage here

https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.cache.CacheManager

Comment: but CacheManager  belongs to Spring .I want to store data in redis cache.

Comment: You can create a Cache with the underlying data store as Redis. In spring boot you need to set `spring.cache.type=redis` and this would create your cache using Redis.

Comment: @Autowired
RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;



redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("KEY","Value");

redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("KEY");
How about above way?